# Achieve react native app layout for landscape and portrait

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am creating the react native app and quite new about this. In this app, I am creating image slider, I want that image slider adjust it's view on both portrait and landscape automatically.

This [Orientation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) checks either the device is in landscape or in portrait view.

Shall I need to write layout/view for **landscape** and **portrait** independently?
Or is there any way that I can follow for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

React native uses flexbox for layout rendering. Using flexbox UI will be same for both landscape and portrait mode.